# Custom Aspect Ratio with AutoLayout

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uikit, ios6, autolayout

Let's say I have a UIView that contains a child UIView which has to be 4:3. I want to solve this problem using AutoLayout in code.

I've been struggling with AutoLayout but I haven't figured out yet how to do this.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

I attach an image to explain better what I mean.
http://d.pr/i/d0Oc

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I figured out.

```
//Given a childView... 
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:childView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:childView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                           multiplier:4.0/3.0 //Aspect ratio: 4*height = 3*width
                           constant:0.0f];
            [childView addConstraint:constraint];
```

Comment: Is this doable from interface builder too?

Comment: Yes it is since Xcode 6! In the Pin Tool there now is an option for Aspect.

Comment: I think it needs to swap NSLayoutAttributeHeight and NSLayoutAttributeWidth. Right now it says 3:4 and not 4:3.

Comment: Also, a good thing to add here, is that you cannot change the multiplier of constraints once they're created - the multiplier property's read-only. One's not able to change the multiplier even by using key paths.

The way to proceed is to remove the constraint at hand and recreate it with the new multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax for Swift 3:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(
  item: item,
  attribute: .width,
  relatedBy: .equal,
  toItem: item,
  attribute: .height,
  multiplier: width / height,
  constant: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try all answers above but didn't work, and this is my solution with swift 3:

```
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: yourView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 560.0/315.0, constant: 0)
yourView.addConstraint(newConstraint)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([newConstraint])  
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(yourView.constraints)
yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
```