# How to manage the gap between two views in auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I am using auto layout for my `ViewController` I know how to define the gap between two views using constraints programmatically. What I want to do now is when the screen size increase, increase the gap also. Because my `UIViews`are positioned properly in iphone 4s and 5s but in 6 and 6 plus they are positioned in a small area of the screen. I know adding multiplier we can set the aspect ratio of a view but, how to increase the gap between 2 views when the screen hight increase.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Let say this image,, there is a logo above this please login label.

This is my verticle position constraint

```
V:|-70-[Title]-130-[lblFirst]-0-[lblSecond]-20-[textusername]-10-[txtpassword]-10-[btnLogin]
```

this Title is an image 130pix above to this Please Login label. I want to increase this 130 when it comes to iphone 6 and 6 plus

Comment: you want the gap height to be relative to the screen size?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your current layout in the storyboard/xib?

Comment: yeas let say I have a image view and 10pix below to that I have another label. But when the screen size increase I dont want to add my label 10pix below to that uiimage view I want to increase that gap

Comment: Do your views have a fixed height or does the height increase with the parent view height?

Comment: see my edited answer. you will find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a UIView with alpha 0 and clear color and use it instead of the gap and use aspect ratio to the view used for gap and top and bottom or left and right whatever your situation to the views between whom you want to make the gap dynamic. And also you need to add some more alignment constraints to the gapView but it will work. I could not found any other method to do this easily so i have used this method everywhere in all projects and all working fine. I think UIView with clear color and alpha 0 will not effect the screen or performance in any way. We can use this.

Here is an example like if you have two text fields vertically and you want to increase the gap between them dynamically then take a view between then with the exact same width of text field and add those constraints.

1) Top of GapView to upper text field.

2) Bottom of GapView to below text field.

3) Equal width to any text field or leading and trailing to superview or main view.

4) Proportional Height to main view(you can add this constraint by adding equal height from subview to any of superview and then by changing the multiplier);

And your GapView will increase and decrease accordingly.

Comment: I guess it's the easiest solution