# How to give the aspect ratio to images in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, aspect-ratio

I've created the image view and set the image dynamically based on the API response. I've set the image and constraints programmatically and didn't use any storyboard files. Currently I am setting the content mode of the image view.  Now I want to set the ratio value to 21:9 to the image programmatically. Is that possible to give the ratio value to the image?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to set ratio to ImageView via constraints to 21:9? If you want to operate on image you should crop it then

Comment: Maybe this one helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43414400/10150796

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set aspect ratio constraints programmatically in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334017/how-can-i-set-aspect-ratio-constraints-programmatically-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 21/9).isActive = true
```